# kill all user connections in SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure

I need to alter a table and the Sql Azure just spins its wheels.

I think its because there is a connection somewhere that is accessing that table.

How can I see who is accessing my tables and how can I terminate their connections.

I am looking for something similar to

```
ALTER DATABASE xxx SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

that will work with sql azure

Comment: By "just spins its wheels", do you mean that you get no message whatsoever? No error of any kind? There is a list of ALTER arguments that SQL Azure does not support on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336286.aspx), but those should all give you error messages.

Comment: Can you please post the actual ALTER statement?  The table schema ("CREATE" script) would be helpful as well.  Single User mode should work in Azure FYI, you just have to connect into the master db

Comment: This does not work as-is in Azure, it fails with "Incorrect syntax near 'SINGLE_USER'."

Comment: For a problem like this, thew next step is not 'kill all users', it is 'investigate the problem and probably learn something'. I always recommend installing `sp_WhoIsActive` in these cases

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sys.dm_exec_connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394101.aspx) to view information about connections to a SQL Azure DB.  Example [here under Monitoring Connections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394114.aspx).  You could block the errant connections at the [SQL Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621782.aspx) level or deny them access to the table you care about with the [security stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182795.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Any valid alter database should drop connection. For instance, you can change the size
ALTER database demo MODIFY (MAXSIZE=5 GB)

Answer (score 1):

Deletes all user sessions on a database except your own (which you aren't allowed to do)

```
DECLARE @mySessionId INT
DECLARE @dbName VARCHAR(50)
SET @dbName = '<Your database name>'
DECLARE @spid int
CREATE TABLE #UserSessions (spid SMALLINT, ecid SMALLINT, [Status] NCHAR(30), loginname NCHAR(128), hostname NCHAR(128), blk CHAR(5), dbname NCHAR(128), cmd NCHAR(16), request_id INT)
INSERT INTO #UserSessions ([spid], ecid, [Status], [loginname], [hostname], blk, [dbname], cmd, request_id) EXEC dbo.sp_who

SELECT @spid = min(spid) FROM #UserSessions WHERE NOT hostname = HOST_NAME() AND dbName = @dbName AND [status] = 'sleeping'
WHILE @spid IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE ('KILL ' + @spid)
    SELECT @spid = min(spid) FROM #UserSessions WHERE NOT hostname = HOST_NAME() AND dbName = @dbName AND spid > @spid AND [status] = 'sleeping'
END

DROP TABLE #UserSessions
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL DB V12 supports setting database into restricted user mode (http://www.sqlindepth.com/alter-database-in-sql-v12/). You can also kill the connections using kill command. Alternatively update the firewall rules just to allow your IP.