# Azure Truncate table

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I recently spun up a sql database on Windows Azure.  I created a couple of tables and loaded some data.  I then went into Sql Server Management Studio on my local machine and typed

```
Truncate table XXXX
```

And now it is clocking "Executing Query".  Is truncate not supported by azure?

Comment: Not supported, or no permission, would have bombed out straight off. Truncate requires an exclusive table lock, so I'd say something has a hold on the table. That's a guess though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tony:

I think you are right.  I used the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801029/kill-all-user-connections-in-sql-azure) and after resizing the db, all of the connections went away and I could truncate without a problem.

Thanks