# 'The ALTER DATABASE statement must be the only statement in the batch'

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to execute the following query on my Windows Azure database
use master

```
ALTER DATABASE Test SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE Test SET MULTI_USER
```

When try to run it I get the error

> The ALTER DATABASE statement must be the only statement in the batch.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this. What I basically want is to close all present connection on my database.

Comment: As a note, SINGLE_USER is not available on SQL Azure V12 currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error implies, your alter statement can be the only in the batch - something like this should work:

```
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 
GO
ALTER DATABASE Test SET MULTI_USER 
GO
```

[GO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx) signifies the end of a batch so each alter statement would be a separate batch.

Comment: Now I get this. 
Incorrect syntax near 'SINGLE_USER'.
Incorrect syntax near 'MULTI_USER'.

Comment: As cbattlegear pointed out, the user mode changes aren't available on azure currently, here's another SO question that seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801029/kill-all-user-connections-in-sql-azure

Comment: Sorry I didn't state that in my answer, I'm not especially familiar with sql azure, just have gotten that error message before and had a solution for it :P

Comment: GO is not required, and this can run as a single batch in SQL Server. Harish is trying it to run on SQLV11 where this is not supported.

Comment: @SirishaChamarthi I understand that, my answer only accounts for the error message OP was receiving, and I further explained in my comments my oversight, and linked to another question very similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to close the connections, you may try setting it to restricted_user. ALTER DATABASE SINGLE USER IS NOT SUPPORTED in V12. If you want to close all the connections and is ok if they reconnect, you can kill them by using Kill statement in combination with sys.dm_Exec_Requests/ The other option is to set ReadOnly and then Read_write. There is no single user option in SQL DB.